# how to create simplest database in lotus domino server on redhat machine

Tags: lotus-domino

I am debugging a software which uses lotus and i am not looking to master the domino lotus.

Looking for commands to

1) create database
2) list database
3) delete database

I had downloaded the DOMI_SRV_901_LIN_XS64_EN_-TRIAL.tar and installed on redhat 6 machine. Started the lotus domino server using the command

```
su - notes -c "cd /local/notesdata; /opt/ibm/lotus/bin/server&"
```

Now how to create the simplest database possible using command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: you don't...

There is no way to create a database using command lines, and deleting and listing is also usually not made via command line.

For creating databases you need IBM Domino Designer Client.
For managing the server you need IBM Domino Admin Client.

Domino databases are not relational databases, that can be simply created using a command: They are much more.

After installing you have a lot databases already on your server. e.g.:

- names.nsf - Aka Domino Directory: Contains the configuration of your Domino Domain, your users, groups, etc.
- log.nsf - Guess: Yes, the log of the server
- admin4.nsf - Needed for administrative purposes (renaming users, deleting databases, etc.), used in the "backend" most of the time

You won't learn using domino just from a linux console. Most probably you need an admin education (lasting at least 3 days)...

Domino is to complex for this...